# PostgreSQL неправильно сортирует укр. текст: ставит вначале буквы "є" и "і".

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица со всеми странами мира на 3 языках: англ, рус, укр.

Первые два сортирует правильно, а украинский вариант не полностью (как видно из заголовка).

Как это можно исправить?

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 2):

Согласно официальным [докам](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html) есть поддержка предложения COLLATE для выбора символьной сортировки

```
SELECT * FROM test1 ORDER BY a || b COLLATE "fr_FR";
```

В вашем случае (для Украины) будет, видимо

```
SELECT * FROM таблица ORDER BY столбец COLLATE "uk_UA";
```